# Using concat in comparison returns everything

Tags: mysql, view, subquery, concatenation

In a view, I have a column that is the concatenation of 2 columns of a table (sqlfiddle example below).

While querying this view (v1), I use a subquery on the same view (v2).
If the link between the two views is a single column (id_part_2), the behavior is the one expected (1 result).

However if the link is the concatenated column ('id'), while the subquery on its own returns a single result, the whole query doesn't apply the where condition (returns every row).

http://sqlfiddle.com./#!9/6c2138/1

The problem is from the `CONCAT` of two columns (no issue if with just `CONCAT('foo', id_part_2)`).

I know the query could be written without the subquery, I know the `CONCAT` could be done only in the end result. However the way the query is written isn't fully in my control. I'm more interested to know why this behavior is so and if there's a way to avoid that behavior.

Side note, I can't reproduce this behavior on my own database (witnessed on a remote server), which makes me believe the database itself could be edited.

Structure (in MySQL 5.6):

```
 CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id_part_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_part_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `search` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_part_1`,`id_part_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
VIEW `view_1` AS
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(`table_1`.`id_part_1`,
        `table_1`.`id_part_2`) AS `id`,
        
    `table_1`.`id_part_2` AS `id_part_2`,
    `table_1`.`search` AS `search`
FROM `table_1`;
        
insert into table_1 values ('A', '1', 'foo1');
insert into table_1 values ('A', '2', 'foo2');
insert into table_1 values ('A', '3', 'foo3');
insert into table_1 values ('B', '4', 'foo4');
insert into table_1 values ('B', '5', 'foo5');
insert into table_1 values ('B', '6', 'foo6');
```

Query OK:

```
SELECT v1.id AS id_1
FROM view_1 v1 
WHERE v1.id_part_2 IN (
    SELECT v2.id_part_2
    FROM view_1 v2 
    WHERE v2.search = 'foo2') 
;
```

Query NOK:

```
SELECT v1.id AS id_1
FROM view_1 v1 
WHERE v1.id IN (
    SELECT v2.id
    FROM view_1 v2 
    WHERE v2.search = 'foo2') 
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a bug in that version

in dbfiddle,uk this works see examole

and also https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exfkgCJpH9X4ped4S2PGpj/1

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
>   `id_part_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `id_part_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   `search` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id_part_1`,`id_part_2`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> CREATE 
>     ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
>     SQL SECURITY INVOKER
> VIEW `view_1` AS
>     SELECT 
>         CONCAT(`table_1`.`id_part_1`,
>                     `table_1`.`id_part_2`) AS `id`,
>             
>         `table_1`.`id_part_2` AS `id_part_2`,
>         `table_1`.`search` AS `search`
>     FROM `table_1`;
>         
> insert into table_1 values ('A', '1', 'foo1');
> insert into table_1 values ('A', '2', 'foo2');
> insert into table_1 values ('A', '3', 'foo3');
> insert into table_1 values ('B', '4', 'foo4');
> insert into table_1 values ('B', '5', 'foo5');
> insert into table_1 values ('B', '6', 'foo6');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT v1.id AS id_1
> FROM view_1 v1 
> WHERE v1.id_part_2 IN (
>     SELECT v2.id_part_2
>     FROM view_1 v2 
>     WHERE v2.search = 'foo2') 
> ;
>
> SELECT v1.id AS id_1
> FROM view_1 v1 
> WHERE v1.id IN (
>     SELECT v2.id
>     FROM view_1 v2 
>     WHERE v2.search = 'foo2') 
> ;
> ```

> ```
> | id_1 |
> | :--- |
> | A2   |
>
> | id_1 |
> | :--- |
> | A2   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8f222f159a5603c5b7525e8b8a903c00)* version